# Auto Generate String Primary Key with Annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, auto-generate

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot and in the model there's an Id (primary key) which is String and I need to auto-generate it when saving new entity.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
```

But, I get this error when saving a new entity.

```
"message": "Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException:
```

How to avoid this error and do the auto generation `id` when a new entity is saved.

Comment: This is very much hibernate only question. Why are you choosing id of datatype String and not an integer/long value?

Comment: Thanks!, I use this app as an API. So, the the request parameters like Id are comes as Strings. That's the reason why.

Comment: This means that id is already being supplied in request and you don't really need to generate it. Remove @GeneratedValue annotation then. Hibernate will consider it as assigned identifier and will not try to enrich itself.

Comment: Well, for the update, id is provided. But, for saving, I need to auto-generate the id.

Comment: In that case follow the answers mentioned below.

Answer (score 7):

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) This will result in any of either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB.

If you look here, you'll notice all of those generate ids of type long, short or int, not of type String.

If you want to generate Id as the string then use generator="uuid" as follows

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not working for you as you attempt to use the `auto` generated value with a `String` field.

In order for this to work you need to change your `@GeneratedValue` annoation to use a `generator` instead of a `strategy` and also add a `@GenericGenerator` annotation naming the generator and poininting over to the strategy.

Assuming for example that you want to produce auto-generated UUIDs as PKs for your table, your code would look like:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String id;
```

Aside for the above, you can always implement `IdentifierGenerator` to create your own generators. You can check here for more:

[How to implement a custom String sequence identifier generator with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747218/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate)