# How to create auto generated primary key for string in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, primary-key

I want to create a primary key of String type, which will be auto-generated by Spring JPA. I want that the primary key should start with "USER****" and it should be of uniform length. e.g. USER0012, USER0007, USER1409 etc. And also want each time next user id will get generate.

I am new to Spring JPA, I know we can generate long or int type of primary key with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` or `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`, but is there any inbuilt mechanism for this?

Comment: Hi, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747218/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate 
As far as I know you need a custom generator.