# How do I get 2 radiobutton list which pass data to mysql db? Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-data-jpa

Main concept of this is: I want to have 2 radio button list. One with trainers and other with trainer's activities. I have two problems:

1. How can I get 2 radio button list with data retrieved from mysql db.

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "trainers")
   public class Trainer {


       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name = "name")
       private String name;

       @Column(name = "pt_done")
       private Integer personalTraining;

       @Column(name = "target")
       private Integer target;

       @Column(name = "sale")
       private Integer sale;

       @Column(name = "steps")
       private Integer steps;

       public Trainer() {}
       //+getters and setters
   }
   ```

   ```
   public interface TrainerRepository extends JpaRepository < Trainer, Integer > {
       @Query(value = "select name from trainers", nativeQuery = true)
       List < Trainer > findByName() @Service
       public class TrainerServiceImplementation implements TrainerService {
           private TrainerRepository trainerRepository;
           @Override
           public List < Trainer > findByName() {
               return trainerRepository.findByName();
           }
           @Controller @RequestMapping("/gym")
           public class TrainerController {
               @Autowired
               private TrainerRepository trainerRepository;
               @Autowired
               private TrainerService trainerService;
               @RequestMapping("/hello")
               public String viewHomePage(Model theModel) {
                   theModel.addAttribute("trainers", trainerRepository.findByName());
                   return "welcome";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **welcome.jsp**

   ```
   <form:form action="nextpage" modelAttribute = "trainers" method="POST">
   <input type="radio" name="name" value="${trainers}"/> John Simson
   ```

   I have no idea how i can retrieve data from db to radiobutton list. I have four trainers.
2. I have to check one of points from first radio button list and one of points from second radio button list. And after I chose 2 options I will redirect to new JSP Page (If checked personal training -> redirect to personaltraining.jsp, etc.)
3. How can I pass data to mysql table, e.g. I chose John Simson and Personal Training, I will fill next jsp page personaltraining.jsp and when i fill and send, I want to save it in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `Spring Thymeleaf` to your project. (I think `Spring JPA` exists.)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Later, it would be healthier to have an id in the `Trainer` entity. [You can also have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15470272/2039546)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

The repository and service that brings all instructors can be like this. (You haven't done a private search!)

```
public interface TrainerRepository extends JpaRepository<Trainer, Integer> {}
```

```
public interface TrainerService {
    List<Trainer> findAll();
}
```

```
@Service
public class TrainerServiceImpl implements TrainerService {

    private final TrainerRepository trainerRepository;

    public TrainerServiceImpl(TrainerRepository trainerRepository) {
        this.trainerRepository = trainerRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Trainer> findAll() {
        return trainerRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/gym")
public class TrainerController {

    private final TrainerService trainerService;

    public TrainerController(TrainerService trainerService) {
        this.trainerService = trainerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("trainers", trainerService.findAll());
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Now if you save the following code in the `resources/templates' folder as` welcome.html`, you can see the trainers from the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Trainers</label>
            <div th:each="trainer : ${trainers}">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="trainer" th:value="${trainer.id}" th:text="${trainer.name}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The result will be as in this picture.**

[image: The result will be as in this picture.]